# Graph Dbs - Positions of nodes - graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, graph-databases, nosql

Say you have a set of nodes containing all the english letters, and your task is to store the words "foo" and "four" just using some general "object1" and "object2" nodes and as many edges as you want..

You will store relationships like

```
(object1)--contains-->(f)
(object1)--contains-->(o)
```

and

```
(object2)--contains-->(f)
(object2)--contains-->(o)
(object2)--contains-->(u)
(object2)--contains-->(r)
```

so you can query on the "contains" relationship to find the letters of the given words.

but then how to store the double "o" in "foo"?

And how to store the letters order for each object?

In other words, how to store relative positions of nodes (ex.: (a) comes before (b))?

And what if those positions must be in a 2d enviroment (ex.: positions of nodes in a grid)?

And how to store multiple, similar but unique, relationships?

P.s: as always I feel my english poor, if something is not clear please ask!

Comment: I feel like working on a node.js / neo4j sollution, Hrabal, could you upvote one of the below pseudocode sollutions, so I know what you are actually looking for?

Comment: Please clarify your objectives: which questions would you try to answer using this gaph?

Answer (score 1):

**if you can assign properties to your relations, other than just the type, you might**

// create bar as relation properties

```
    create (bar)
    create (bar)-[:contains{order:0]->(b)
    create (bar)-[:contains{order:1]->(a)
    create (bar)-[:contains{order:2]->(r)
```

// create food as relation properties

```
    create (food)
    create (food)-[:contains{order:0]->(f)
    create (food)-[:contains{order:1]->(o)
    create (food)-[:contains{order:2]->(o)
    create (food)-[:contains{order:3]->(d)
```

This is supported by Neo4j, thought the pseudo code above is not immediately usable

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical example of linked lists in graphs, assume the word **cool** , he can be stored like this :

```
(word:Word {name:"cool"})-[:FIRST]->(c)-[:NEXT]->(o)-[:NEXT]->(o)-[:NEXT]->(l)<-[:LAST]-(word)
```

This representation may help you having insights about the letters like :

- At which position the letter o is the most placed
- All the words having the ool letters combination
- Get all the words starting with the "all"

Here a neo4j console with the graph representation http://console.neo4j.org/r/uzwded

The insert query, in case of console issues :

```
MERGE (cool:Word {name:'cool'})
MERGE (fool:Word {name:'fool'})
MERGE (cold:Word {name:'cold'})
CREATE (cool)-[:FIRST]->(:Letter {name:'c'})-[:NEXT]->(:Letter {name:'o'})-[:NEXT]->(:Letter {name:'o'})-[:NEXT]->(:Letter {name:'l'})<-[:LAST]-(cool)
CREATE (fool)-[:FIRST]->(:Letter {name:'f'})-[:NEXT]->(:Letter {name:'o'})-[:NEXT]->(:Letter {name:'o'})-[:NEXT]->(:Letter {name:'l'})<-[:LAST]-(fool)
CREATE (cold)-[:FIRST]->(:Letter {name:'c'})-[:NEXT]->(:Letter {name:'o'})-[:NEXT]->(:Letter {name:'l'})-[:NEXT]->(:Letter {name:'d'})<-[:LAST]-(cold)
```

Comment: How would you present "cool", "cold" and "fool" in the same graph, Christophe?

Comment: Oops, Christophe, do you realize you created about a dozen of "o"-nodes in your model? Further: I see no connection between words having letters in common, which, I suppose, is essential for Hrabal.

Comment: Mmh no I do not see thousands of nodes, maybe a problem with the console instance. and I see nowhere questions about relating nodes having letters in common. You will related almost all your database if you do it ?

Comment: And, if you want to find words having for e.g. the combination "oo" in words, you can just run this query : MATCH (o:Letter { name:'o' }),(o2:Letter { name:'o' })
WHERE o <> o2
MATCH (w:Word)-[:FIRST|NEXT*]->(o)-[:NEXT]->(o2)
RETURN w.name

Comment: assuming of course there is an index on :Letter(name)

Comment: A dozen = 12, Chjristo

Comment: Hi @ChristopheWillemsen , the problem (as @DirkHorsten said) is that I need connections between words with letters in common (Real world use: there will be no words and letters but "things" and shared "bricks"). But your `FIRST->NEXT->LAST` approach intrigues me, think I'll try with a combination of yours and Dirk's approach, thanks

Comment: Hrabal, you might find useful information if you search the web for "network database circular linked list". These concepts from half a century ago come back to life now in graph databases.

Answer (score 0):

**Probably the neatest solution is to use linked lists**

// create bar as linked list

```
    create (ar)-[:start]->(a)
    create (ar)-[:proceed]->(r)
    create (bar)-[:start]->(b)
    create (bar)-[:proceed]->(ar)
```

// create food as linked list

```
    create (od)-[:start]->(o)
    create (od)-[:proceed]->(d)
    create (ood)-[:start]->(o)
    create (ood)-[:proceed]->(od)
    create (food)-[:start]->(f)
    create (food)-[:proceed]->(ood)
```